# Format Date as MM/dd/yyyy in MVC Textbox

Tags: c#, date, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a textbox in MVC5 that shows a date in it. The date is coming from webAPI formatted as a string, and in my model it is a string as well. It shows data like `10/16/2015 12:00:00 AM`.  How can I delete the `12:00:00 AM` part?  I tried this, but it is not working as I am guessing the type should be DateTime:

```
 Letter Date:</td><td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.LetterDate,"{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", new { @class = "TextBoxAsLabel", id = "LetterDate" })
```

Is there any other way without changing the model type to DateTime?

None of the links provided are in MVC.

Comment: You could use a substring call, or split it by space, then take the first element in the array.  Otherwise, if you're wanting a custom control of the format as a date, you will need to first convert it to a datetime - `new DateTime(dateTimeString).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")`

Comment: @krillgar - not a duplicate because that is asking how to format a `DateTime` object.  This is asking how to format a string as a `DateTime`, and if it's possible to do so without converting the string to a `DateTime` first.

Comment: You're right. I didn't read it close enough. The title, major points of the question, and property name all pointed to it being a DateTime property.

Comment: I had to reread it too to catch that last part.  No worries.

Comment: @Nick Thanks, but not sure how to use it inside the MVC textbox. this is not woking : DateTime( Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.LetterDate.ToString("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}"), new { class = "TextBoxAsLabel", id = "LetterDate" })

Comment: @Alma - you would want `@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.LetterDate, new DateTime(dateString).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"), new { @class = "TextBoxAsLabel", @id = "LetterDate" })` or something very close to that.  You have to construct the DateTime object inside the TextBoxFor since that is what you are using to set the default value of the textbox.

Comment: There is no reason the Model should not have the value as a DateTime.

Comment: @Nick the problem is dateString. what should I replace it with?

Comment: @Alma, that is the string that is coming across from your webAPI call, my assumption is that it would be `Model.LetterDate`

Comment: @Nick, I was replacing that but it has error that "Best overload method of system.DateTime.Date has some invalid argument.

Comment: Letter Date:</td><td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => ((DateTime)model.LetterDate).ToShortDateString(), new { @class = "TextBoxAsLabel", id = "LetterDate" })  This is really not a great way to do this in general though...  For example, if the value of model.LetterDate is not castable to a DateTime type, you will throw an exception.  The best way would be to clean up the data being applied to the model before sending it to your view.